# The definition of black-height in Red-Black tree

Tags: red-black-tree

I am reading CLRS page 309, and I am confused by the definition of `black-height` of RBT.

The definition in in this book is

> the number of black nodes on any simple path from, but not including,
>   a node x down to a leaf

I also referred to wikipedia, `black-height` is defined as

> the uniform number of black nodes in all paths from root to the leaves

and geeksforgeeks.org

> Black height is number of black nodes on a path from a node to a leaf.
>   Leaf nodes are also counted black nodes.

But none of them give examples, especially no edge cases.

Can you explain it with the following cases?

What is the `black-height` of a RBT:

1. nil
2. B-(nil nil)
3. ```
   B-R-B-(nil nil)
    \ \
     \ B-(nil nil)
      B-(nil nil)
   ```

By the definition of CLRS, I calculate the `black-height` of root is

1. 0
2. 1
3. 2

(In my opinion, am I right?)

And in CLRS lemma 13.1's proof, `height` is also used. What is the `height` of the above three trees?

1. 0
2. 1
3. 2

(In my opinion, am I right?)

And, what is the `black-height` of a tree?

1. 1
2. 2
3. 3

(not sure, I doubt the wikipedia's definition is different from the definition from CLRS)

And also, Exercise 13.1-1 uses this definition.

Comment: Your computation is right, and the black-height of a tree is the balck-height of its root.